# Comparing number cast to string in str list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have a list of string numbers and a counter inside a for loop. If the counter is in the list I do something, like this:

```
codes = ['123','1245','564','8920','57498']
f = open('path_to_file','r')
for lineno, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
    if str(lineno) in codes:
        print str(lineno) + ' is in the list'
```

The problem is that it seems that the if condition is always true from a certain point, because once lineno = 123 it always print the sentence inside the if block.

Anyone see something wrong with this code? Thanks

Comment: Nonsense. Set a variable like `i = 122`. `str(i) in codes` is False. Increment it: True. Increment again: False. Took me 7 lines in an interpreter to demonstrate with completely novice-friendly code that your "if condition is always true from a certain point" assumption is bad. Is this your real code?

Comment: Why are you saying `f = open(...)` then enumerating `file`?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this error -- are you sure this is exactly how you're coding it? http://pastebin.com/w232SzaV

Comment: You might miss somethings. I tested, it looked ok.

Answer (score 0):

I code bellow:

```
In [8]: codes = ['1', '3', '4']

In [9]: f = open("test.py", "r")

In [10]: for lineno, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
   ....:     if str(lineno) in codes:
   ....:         print str(lineno) + ' is in the list'
   ....:
1 is in the list
3 is in the list
4 is in the list
```

It looks OK.